# PHP PDO while doesn't achieve my desire end result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my first posting in SO, my apologize if I opened an existing question. As I couldn't find the result in Google. Sorry to said but I'm still fresh in PHP PDO and in learning stage.

Back to my question, currently I'm building a customer visit logs from my wife but I'm stuck with the result. I have two table which one stores the customer information and another table store the visit details. I uploaded the test table at here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01d3ea/1)

And below is my current coding and I'm using PHP PDO **while**

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$p_id = $_GET['name'];

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT customer.fname, customer.lname, customer.gender, services.treatment, services.date
          FROM customer LEFT JOIN services
          ON customer.id = services.customer_id
          WHERE customer.slug  LIKE :id";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array('id' => $p_id));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Customer Record</h1>
Name: <br />
Gender: <br />    
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Customer Gender</th>
            <th>Treatment</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['fname']), ' ', htmlspecialchars($r['lname'])?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['gender']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['treatment']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['date']); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <a href="search.html">Seach Again</a>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

And I achieve as what SQL Fiddle result, but what I wanted is, the name and gender is not keep repeating.

I attached together with the screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JySGz.jpg)

What I want is as per the screenshot image, **Name:** John Doe and **Gender:** Male, should be on top and not keep on repeating while the table below show all the visit details. I tried to modified the code but it seems it don't really work out.

Please advise me as I'm really out of idea how to achieve what I want.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do a `LEFT JOIN` in your SQL query, you know ahead of time that all of the `fname`, `lname` and `gender` values returned by `$q->fetch()` are going to be for the *same* `customer.slug`, right? So you can count on that.

My suggestion would be to instead use the [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function to get an array of all records for `customer.slug`, and then render that in your view. For example (haven't tested this) you could add the following after `$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` ...

```
$cs = $q->fetchAll();   // customer services join
```

Then, in your `<html>` view, you could do something like the following:

```
<h1>Customer Record</h1>
Name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($cs[0]['fname'].' '.$cs[0]['lname']); ?> <br />
Gender: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($cs[0]['gender']); ?> <br />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Treatment</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($cs as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['treatment']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['date']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Of course, it might also be a good idea to check to see that *any* records were returned by your query and display a "not found" message if not. After all, `$cs[0]` might be empty, giving you a PHP error.